# My ASP.NET website does not run on remote server (Website panel)

Tags: asp.net

this is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Home.htm" />
                <add value="Home.html" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

when I run run the website www.blah.co.za I get the following error

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: another thing which I do not understand is that my web.config not have *<customErrors mode="Off"/>*

Comment: Try following the directions to see the underlying reason for your error.

Comment: If you don't have customErrors mode="Off" in your config, you will see this message regardless if you are just running it locally. Modify your config file and re-deploy - that will show you the underlying error message.